# Import bom based on property/profile

Tags: maven, maven-bom

I have a situation where in environment A I want to use maven BOM-A in a service for its dependencies and in environment B for the same service I want to use maven BOM-B for its dependencies.
How can I make a distinction between which BOM-* I want to import depending on a property/profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can put dependencyManagement entries into profiles, but if you always want to build similar projects for two platforms, you can also think about creating a multi-module project.

Then you would have `module-A`, `module-B` and `common`, so that most of the code and configuration is in `common` and the environment specific POM entries are in the other modules